# Retrying failed futures in Python's ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I want to implement retry logic with Python's `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. I would like the following properties:

1. A new future is added to the work queue as soon as it fails.
2. A retried future can be retried again, either indefinitely or up to a maximum retry count.

A lot of existing code I found online basically operates in "rounds", where they call `as_completed` on an initial list of futures, resubmits failed futures, gathers those futures in a new list, and goes back to calling `as_completed` on the new list if it's not empty. Basically something like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(...) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(fn, job): job for job in jobs}
    while len(futures) > 0:
        new_futures = {}
        for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            if fut.exception():
                job = futures[fut]
                new_futures[executor.submit(fn, job)] = job
            else:
                ...  # logic to handle successful job
        futures = new_futures
```

However, I think that doesn't satisfy the first property, since it's possible that a retried future completes before the initial futures, but we won't process it until all the initial futures complete.

Here's a hypothetical pathological case. Let's say we have two jobs, the first runs for 1 second but has a 90% chance of failure, while the second runs for 100 seconds. If our executor has 2 workers, and the first job fails after 1 second, we'll retry it immediately. But if it failed again, we won't be able to retry until the second job completes.

---

So my question is, is it possible to implement retry logic with these desired properties, without using external libraries or rewriting low-level executor logic? One thing I tried is putting the retry logic in the code sent to the worker:

```
def worker_job(fn):
    try:
        return fn()
    except Exception:
        executor.submit(fn)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(...) as executor:
    jobs = [functools.partial(fn, arg) for arg in args]
    executor.map(worker_job, jobs)
```

But it seems like submitting new jobs from within a job doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Retry using `as_completed`

### Simple way

Loop with `wait(..., return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` instead of `as_completed(...)`.

Trade-offs:

1. Overhead of `pending` futures (re-adding waiter, building `new_futures`).
2. Troublesome if want to specify overall `timeout`.

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(fn, job): job for job in jobs}
    while len(futures) > 0:
        new_futures = {}
        done, pending = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for fut in done:
            if fut.exception():
                job = futures[fut]
                new_futures[executor.submit(fn, job)] = job
            else:
                ...  # logic to handle successful job
        for fut in pending:
            job = futures[fut]
            new_futures[fut] = job
        futures = new_futures
```

### Efficient way

Tweak `as_completed(...)` to add to `fs` and `pending`, and use `waiter`.

Trade-off: Maintenance.

Advantage: Ability to specify overall `timeout` if wanted.

```py
class AsCompletedWaiterWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fs = None
        self.pending = None
        self.waiter = None

    def listen(self, fut):
        with self.waiter.lock:
            self.fs.add(fut)
            self.pending.add(fut)
            fut._waiters.append(self.waiter)

    def as_completed(self, fs, timeout=None):
        """
        concurrent.futures.as_completed plus the 3 lines marked with +.
        """
        if timeout is not None:
            end_time = timeout + time.monotonic()

        fs = set(fs)
        total_futures = len(fs)
        with _AcquireFutures(fs):
            finished = set(
                    f for f in fs
                    if f._state in [CANCELLED_AND_NOTIFIED, FINISHED])
            pending = fs - finished
            waiter = _create_and_install_waiters(fs, _AS_COMPLETED)
        self.fs = fs            # +
        self.pending = pending  # +
        self.waiter = waiter    # +
        finished = list(finished)
        try:
            yield from _yield_finished_futures(finished, waiter,
                                               ref_collect=(fs,))

            while pending:
                if timeout is None:
                    wait_timeout = None
                else:
                    wait_timeout = end_time - time.monotonic()
                    if wait_timeout < 0:
                        raise TimeoutError(
                                '%d (of %d) futures unfinished' % (
                                len(pending), total_futures))

                waiter.event.wait(wait_timeout)

                with waiter.lock:
                    finished = waiter.finished_futures
                    waiter.finished_futures = []
                    waiter.event.clear()

                # reverse to keep finishing order
                finished.reverse()
                yield from _yield_finished_futures(finished, waiter,
                                                   ref_collect=(fs, pending))

        finally:
            # Remove waiter from unfinished futures
            for f in fs:
                with f._condition:
                    f._waiters.remove(waiter)
```

Usage:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(fn, job): job for job in jobs}
    w = AsCompletedWaiterWrapper()
    for fut in w.as_completed(futures):
        if fut.exception():
            job = futures[fut]
            new_fut = executor.submit(fn, job)
            futures[new_fut] = job
            w.listen(new_fut)
        else:
            ...  # logic to handle successful job
```

## Retry from job helper

Wait for `events` in `with ... executor:` as `ThreadPoolExecutor.__exit__` shuts down `executor` so it cannot schedule new futures.

Trade-offs:

1. Would not work with `ProcessPoolExecutor` due to `executor` reference in main process.
2. Troublesome if want to specify overall timeout.

```py
def worker_job(fn, event):
    try:
        rv = fn()
        event.set()
        return rv
    except Exception:
        executor.submit(worker_job, fn, event)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    jobs = [functools.partial(fn, arg) for arg in args]
    events = [threading.Event() for _ in range(len(jobs))]
    executor.map(worker_job, jobs, events)
    for e in events:
        e.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The simple way works when the total number of futures is small, but probably doesn't scale well. The efficient way is probably the best shot here, and is actually quite simple if not counting the repeated code. I'm also surprised at how non-extensible the `concurrent.futures` library is.

Comment: Do you also know by any chance why the approach of submitting new jobs from within a job doesn't work?

Comment: In that implementation, `ThreadPoolExecutor.__exit__` shuts down `executor` so it cannot schedule new futures. I've added a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> But if it failed again, we won't be able to retry until the second job completes.

but I don't think that's true.  The code says:

`for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):`

which is a little bit subtle in that `futures` there is used not as a dictionary, but as an iterator, specifically an iterator of futures to check for completion of.  This iterator provides the set of futures to check for completion, and then `as_completed()` yields them as they complete.  So in your pathological case, the 1s job would indeed be able to be retried many times before the 100s job finishes.

Comment: I don't think that's right. `as_completed` would convert `fs` (its first argument, the `futures` dict here) to a set, so even if it's an iterator that will yield new futures once they're submitted, it wouldn't work here. This is true in Python 3.9 at least, not sure about other versions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple working example on how to retry concurrent using as_completed + while until all tasks succeeds or a general timeout for the whole process:

```
from random import random
from time import sleep, time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
 
# task that sleeps and could fail
def work(identifier):
    sleep(random())
    # fail chance of 80%
    if random() <  0.8:
        raise Exception(f'Something bad happened {identifier}')
    return f'Completed {identifier}'
 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
        futures_to_data = {executor.submit(work, i):i for i in range(10)}
        
        timeout_start = time()
        max_run_time = 4 #seconds
        while len(futures_to_data) > 0 and time() < timeout_start + max_run_time:
            for future in as_completed(futures_to_data):
                if future.exception():
                    data = futures_to_data[future]
                    future_retry = executor.submit(work, data)
                    futures_to_data[future_retry] = data
                    print(f'Failure, adding to retry {data}')
                else:
                    print(f'Success, {future.result()}')

                del futures_to_data[future]

            print(f'Retires, {futures_to_data.values()}, time remaining {timeout_start + max_run_time - time()}')
```

Comment: IIUC this exhibits the same issue as the snippet in the question description -- `as_completed` doesn't yield results of the new futures submitted in the loop. Modifying the `futures_to_data` dictionary doesn't change what `as_completed` yields back, unless the function's implementation has been updated since I last checked.

Comment: Thats true, just added a working full example of how to retry futures (with timeout and deletion of failed futures)